# Github actions: Seeking a branch level property that is visible to both pull request events and workflow dispatch events

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-api, github-actions

I'm looking for a configurable property in github, like a tag or a label, that meets the following requirements:

1. Is associated with a specific branch but across all commits (this eliminates tags)
2. Is visible to both pull request and workflow dispatch events (I believe this eliminates labels)

The use case is that for a particular branch for which a pull request has been generated, I would like a github action to be able to determine if a heroku deployment has already been done. I was thinking of attaching a label after a deployment has been completed, but as stated above, there doesn't seem to be a way for a workflow dispatch event to access properties associated with a pull request (unless I'm missing something).

I suppose one option that always exists is to set up some type of datastore outside of github where we would maintain the deployment status, but I was hoping to avoid the extra maintenance effort.

Comment: GitHub has deployments which you can use, but they're per commit, not per branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I couldn't find a construct that matched the requirements so we ended up setting up the external data store.